# How to handle any text encoding while processing text operations?

Tags: command-line, gedit, text-processing, encoding

I am am having terrible output in gedit:  See the image below: 
[image: Terrible input]

Where as when I tried to open on the command terminal, I was able to see the output  :

```
aims@aims:~/Downloads/worldwide 3/output$ head -n5 My10.txt 

 990.net
 aol.com
 dataone.in.
 mail.hf.ah.cn.
```

I do not understand why this difference in output in Ubuntu 16.04.
If I want to process the text on Ubuntu, how I can get rid of the encoding?
I am fed up of converting one text file to another encoding. Is there any solution that will automatically detect and convert the file to human readable format? I do not want to check the file encoding everytime and then convert to the readable one. I want that this should happen automatically. If the encoding is not available then it should get downloaded.
Is there any solution on Ubuntu to convert the file automatically, so that I can process on those files?
Kindly help me.

Comment: Please post an example of the actual file. We can't help much unless we know what the actual problem is.

Comment: @terdon Actually, the file is utf-8 character encoded. I tried to make it done with the python script while opening it. But the problem I think is not exactly the encoding, but the characters itself. Say the `gedit` is not able to read some characters, while are not exactly the english characters. May that is the reason. Actually, I tried to copy and paste the content of the file but could not paste it. Hence I use the `cat` command and what I got was readable characters. Hence, that is making the problem a bit fuzzy to explain.

Comment: I know. That's why I asked you to post an example of the actual file.